# iOS- TableViewCell expand/collapse

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, tableview

i want to create a a TableView with expand/collapse cells, and i thought 2 ways to achieve that:

1. Play with the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
2. Create 2 different cell, with different identifier, and each time load the right one.

I want the cell to expand/collapse with animation, and the user can expand more then one cell.

Which one is better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What will appear after user will expand a cell view ? It's exactly the same cell with something extra hidden by default and expended on demand ? Or the cell layout will be completely changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your cell, before and after collapsing, and whether you want to animate it or not.

Options:

1. If the contents are the same, or with some small additions, and you wanna animate it. Use this option.
2. If the contents changes dramatically, go with this option. And I'm not sure if animation in this case is easy.

Good luck, need more help, let me know! ;D

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this: https://github.com/seletz/CocoaTreeViewExample

I have made a expandable/collapsable treeview using the same code that is looking like this in my application now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was after something similar, I wanted to be able to show and hide contextMenu for a table view cell. So I ended up using just one cell for both expanded and collapsed state, and I had a "context menu subview" (that's what I wanted for the expanded look) and updated it's frame for the animation.
The trick is that when you want to expand/collapse you cell with a nice animation you'd better use `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` instead of `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` methods. Something like that:

```
// setContextMenuHidden:animated: updates frame and alpha for the context menu
// view (which is a subview of cell content view)
[cell setContextMenuHidden:NO animated:YES];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```